# Big O time complexity of "Merging 2 Packages" problem

Tags: algorithm, big-o

On one of these coding interview prep websites, I was given this question:

> Merging 2 Packages Given a package with a weight limit limit and an
>   array arr of item weights, implement a function
>   getIndicesOfItemWeights that finds two items whose sum of weights
>   equals the weight limit limit. Your function should return a pair [i,
>   j] of the indices of the item weights, ordered such that i > j. If
>   such a pair doesn’t exist, return an empty array.
>
> Analyze the time and space complexities of your solution.
>
> Example:
>
> input:  arr = [4, 6, 10, 15, 16],  lim = 21
>
> output: [3, 1] # since these are the indices of the
>                  # weights 6 and 15 whose sum equals to 21

Initially I was thinking of a solution which iterated over the the array, then an inner loop to iterate over the remaining array to check if the compliment exists (limit - elementA = elementB).

Here's my code:

```
def get_indices_of_item_weights(arr, limit):    
    for idx, i in enumerate(arr):
        diff = limit - i          
        if diff in arr[idx+1:]:   # constant lookup
            for idx2, j in enumerate(arr[idx+1:]):
                if j == diff:
                    return [idx+idx2+1, idx]
    return []
```

The website explained that a solution like this is still O(N^2) time complexity.  But isn't it diminishing in time complexity since the remaining array becomes smaller?  i.e. O(log N).

Can someone help explain why that approach is not O(log N)?

Comment: fwiw.  the more efficient solution is to store values you've come across in a hash table.  so you search the array once and the time complexity is O(N).

Comment: That is *expected* time `O(N)`, but not worst case time.

Answer (score 1):

For each of the first half the packages, you have to look at all of the second half of packages.  That right there gives a lower bound of `(n/2) * (n/2) = n^2 / 4 = O(n^2)` comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

You are enumerating all pairs (i, j) where j > i. There are N * N numbers (i,j) with no restrictions. Subtracting off (i,i) we have N * N - N numbers. Now each pair occurs exactly twice as e.g. (1,2) and (2,1) so divide by two to find the number of all pairs (i,j) with k > i as (N*N - N) / 2 which is still O(N*2).

Check N=4 expect (4*4 - 4) / 2 = 6

1,2 1,3 1,4

2,3 2,4

3,4

Answer (score 0):

Sorting the array is O(n log n).  Finding a suitable pair is O(n) using a sorted array, as may be found by walking inwards from the ends of the sorted array.  Starting with (1, n), then, for each pair (j, i), with j < i: Unless the target was found, or the target was not found and i = j + 1, then if the sum is less than the target, add one to j, and repeat, else the sum is greater than the target, add subtract one from i, and repeat.  The time is either O(n log n) or O(n), depending on whether the array is initially sorted.  The space needed depends on the sort algorithm.  Finding the pair on a sorted array has constant storage required.